# Ajax live search no output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I am a beginner in php and jQuery so an early sorry if my question is stupid. I have been searching quite a lot on ajax live search but there is not much help on internet... So when I type something in my input box nothing comes out, so I thought it was a problem to connect to the database but that works fine. And now I don't really know what to do because my code sounds right (even though it's not :-) ). If someone could help me it would be great thank you.

Here are the codes:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>live search test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      functon getNames(value) {
        $.post("fetch.php",{partialName:value},function(data)
          $("#results").html(data);
        });
      }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="getNames(this.value)">
    <br>
    <div id="results">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("smartphone")or die(mysql_error());


$partialName = $_POST['partialName'];

$names = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM smartphone WHERE name LIKE '%$partialName%'");
while ($name = mysql_fetch_array($names)) {
    echo"<div>".$name['name']."</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your mysql query is susceptible to SQL injection, please switch mysql_query for bound PDO parameters. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Don't just echo the result in your php code. Make an XML or json format of the required html you want to show, and return the formatted data. Then just show it in your jquery.

Comment: @tom alert the response and check.. alert(data), whether request,responding or not, you can also check that on console, network tab..responses and ajax calls

Comment: @H.Jabi Why should he not return just HTML? It's simple and effective for proof of concept.

Comment: I will do so,  thank you.

Comment: @Vaviloff Isn't that a general choice of working with AJAX? Yes, of course he can just return the html. Though it has some drawbacks like handling forms or advanced css techniques, his HTML snippet is simple and will do the job in easiest way. But I have seen people returning the html snippet by encoding it in json. That's just what I suggested: working with json. Of course I can be wrong.

Comment: Yes, @H.Jabi you're quite right to suggest a better practice, though in case of this question it could distract poster from the actual problem he's yet to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you check your browser console tool, you will see '$ is undefined'.

Unless it was for this example, the following is incorrect:

```
<script scr="jquery.js"></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Please also switch your insecure SQL query to the secure PDO bound parameters style, to avoid being exploited.

Comment: I can't see a difference between the two "jquery.js" and thank you i will secure my code

Comment: @tom3883 `scr` vs. `src`. the correct is src, as in source.